# how to capture html tables using TCL http package

Tags: http, tcl

how to capture html tables using TCL http package with an example

I have tried with an example but it simple log out from the session.

```
package require http
package require base64
set auth "Basic [base64::encode XXXX:XXXXX]"
set headerl [list Authorization $auth]
set query "http://100.59.262.156/"
set tok [http::geturl $query -headers $headerl]
set res [http::data $tok]
http::status $tok

# After login  into the session, i am moving one page another web page

set  goquery [http::formatQuery "http://100.59.262.156/web/sysstatus.html"]

# After this i am log out from the session. I am unable to find reason.

set tok [http::geturl $query -query http://100.59.262.156/web/sysstatus.html]
set res [http::data $tok]

# After this i will get a table output i need capture this table
# how to capture tables using 

http::status $tok
```

Thanks

Malli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some misconceptions I see here:

- You should cleanup the tokens that `http::geturl` returns. You do that with `http::cleanup $token`. Otherwise you get memory leaks.
- The basic auth headers has to be send for every request. It is usually enough to request the desired site with the right headers.
- `http::formatQuery` is for POST or GET parameters, not for the URL (you can use it for the query URL part, but not for the entire URL). Drop that.
- The http package does not parse HTML for you. You have to do that yourself. I suggest using [tdom](http://tdom.github.io/)

Because I don't know what your site returns, I can't tell you how to parse it, but here a script to get started:

```
package require http
package require base64
package require tdom

set auth "Basic [base64::encode XXXX:XXXXX]"
set headerl [list Authorization $auth]
set url "http://100.59.262.156/web/sysstatus.html"

set tok [http::geturl $url -headers $headerl]
# TODO: Check the status here. If you get a 403, the login information was not correct.
set data [http::data $tok]
# Important: cleanup
http::cleanup $tok

# Now parse it
dom parse -html $data doc
# Search for the important stuff, walk over the dom... to the the important information
```

Comment: You were missing the `-html` flag to the parser; without it, it parses XML which is relatively unlikely to come back from that sort of URL…

Comment: Thanks Johannes, here i amsuccesfully logged into session, when i moved next page, immedately i am logged out from session.  document.getElementById('logoutMessage').innerHTML = "Session has been logged out due to missing user info.<br>Clearing browser cookies can cause this kind of logout.";

Comment: I think i need to enable cookies, how do i enable cookies for this session.

Comment: state(charset)         = iso8859-1
state(coding)          =
state(currentsize)     = 8899
state(http)            = HTTP/1.0 200 Ok
state(meta)            = Server {ADTRAN TinyServer} MIME-version 1.0 Content-Type text/html Expires -1 Content-Length 9080
state(querylength)     = 0
state(queryoffset)     = 0
state(sock)            = sock5
state(state)           = eof
state(status)          = ok
state(totalsize)       = 9080
state(type)            = text/html

Comment: As I said: always send the authentification header. Each time. For every request.

Comment: I am using header for each geturl, but after login i am moving next page like as mentiond above. Here i am using two URLs one for login like http://100.59.262.156 and then i am moving to http://100.59.262.156/web/sysstatus.html. I am using headers for these request.